# How to update the weights of a model only if loss for current batch is smaller than previous

Tags: pytorch, gradient, optimizer-hints

I'm trying to update the weights of a model during training only for those batches in which the loss is smaller than that obtained in the previous batch.

So, in the batches loop, I store the loss obtained at each iteration, and then I have tried evaluating a condition: if loss at time t-1 is smaller that that a time t, then I proceed as follows:

```
if loss[t-1] <= loss[t]:
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
else:
  #do nothing  or what ?
```

Then, nothing should be done in the else part. Nonetheless, I get an error saying CUDA is running out of memory.

Of course, before computing the loss, I perform an optimizer.zero_grad() sentence.

The for loop that runs over batches seems to be running fine, but memory usage blows up. I read that maybe setting gradients to None would prevent the weights update process but I have tried many sentences (`output.clone().detach()` also `optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)`) but I'm not sure they work. I think they did not. Nonetheless, the memory usage explosion still occurs.

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Are you working on your computer or in Google Colab or similar?

Comment: In Google Colab most of the time. However, I can run the code locally as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when storing losses from consecutive steps.
The out-of-memory error is caused because you are storing the losses in a *list*. The computational graphs will still remain and will stay in memory as long as you keep a reference to your losses. An easy fix is to detach the tensor when you append it to the *list*:

```
# loss = loss_fn(...)
losses.append(loss.detach())
```

Then you can work with

```
if losses[t] <= losses[t-1]: # current loss is smaller
    losses[t].backward()
    optimizer.step()
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not too familiar with pytorch since just have started using it for a project I'm currently working on.  Now, due to your explanation I see the importance of the `loss.detach()` sentence as a way to free up some memory that has been unnecessarily occupied.  Your solution (with some workaround in my script) did the trick. Haven't received the message any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the loss in a list would store the whole graph for that batch for each element in losses. Instead what you can do is the following:

```py
losses.append(loss.cpu().tolist())
optimizer.zero_grad()
if losses[-1] <= losses[-2]: # current loss is smaller
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

As you only update the model if the current loss is smaller than the previous one you don't actually need to store all the losses. The last one and the value of the previous one is enough. Otherwise if you want to store a finite number of graphs you need to be careful about your available memory which is quite limited in many applications.